# uic can't find shared library

Tags: linux, qt5

I am trying to make a Qt5 part of my source tree, so I haven't installed it on my machine, just copied it from source control. I am having a problem when I try to run uic.exe:

```
    stiopa@stiopa-VirtualBox:~/ct/LinuxLibs/Qt/bin > ./uic

    ./uic: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Core.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am still getting the same error even when I copy the libQt5Core library to bin directory. How is uic looking for shared libraries? Is there any environment variable I need to set to fix it?

Comment: you can use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/ct/LinuxLibs/Qt/bin` to set the binary to search for the libraries in the current bin directory - it only affects the current terminal. You would be better installing properly via a package manager; or if compiling manually installing it into one of the standard locations that is picked up by the linker cache

Comment: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH has fixed it. Thanks Petesh!

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another case of not putting the dependent shared libraries in a defined location that is supported by the program.

If you're planning on doing the 'copy the files to the same directory as the executable', the fast solution is to reference the directory in the library load path; e.g. if the binary is in `$HOME/foo`, you do:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:}$HOME/foo
```

This adds or makes `$HOME/foo` the run-time-linker's load path. As a result, any programs you run will look in this directory for libraries, as well as the default set for the OS (defined by the `ld.so` configuration), as well as the paths that are defined within the application itself (the `rpath`).

If you're going to follow this route, what you can do is to move the binary to target.bin, create a target bash script, which invokes the bin file automatically; e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash -p
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:}$(dirname $0)
exec $0.bin "$*"
```

A secondary mechanism which will permit you to change the search location for a binary; without requiring an environment variable insert is to modify the binary so that it searches in different locations than it usually does; this takes advantage of some features in the run-time linker (which looks for libraries).

There is a program called [chrpath](https://alioth.debian.org/frs/?group_id=31052), which can be added by various package managers, which allows you to edit the rpath directly. In this case; you can change the additional search path of the binary using:

```
chrpath -r '$ORIGIN' foo
```

This means that the program will look in the same directory as the binary for `.so` files, thus allowing it to run.